# Firebase Múltiplas Cláusulas

Tags: firebase, firestore

Estou querendo fazer uma consulta com múltiplas cláusulas **where**, com o banco de dados **Firestore**, porém me retorna um erro, fiz uma pesquisa rápida eu vi que o **Firestore** só deixa fazer uma única cláusula **where** em uma **coleção**; eu tentei fazer uma consulta separada e depois junta-las, mas sem sucesso. Ele acaba por retornar os dados duplicados.

No exemplo abaixo eu tenho uma loja, e nessa loja eu tenho alguns produtos, o usuário pode fazer uma filtragem pelo "nome do produto" e também pelo "preço do produto"

O erro que eu obtenho quando tento fazer esta operação é esta exception:

```
All where filters with an inequality (<, <=, >, or >=) must be on the same field. But you have inequality filters on 'FieldPath([name_product])' and 'FieldPath([price])'.
```

Quando tento utilizar um método como este:

```
db.collection('store')
  .where('name_product', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 'name_product')
  .where('name_product', isLessThanOrEqualTo: 'name_product' + "\uf8ff")
  .where('price', isGreaterThan: '10000')
  .snapshots();
```

O exemplo a acima foi escrito em linguagem Dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não pode passar múltiplas condições para o where(). Mas você pode chamar o where quantas vezes for preciso.

[veja este exemplo (em inglês)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64707867/how-to-search-through-multiple-fields-in-my-firestore-database-through-flutter)

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.